# phpunit Functional Tests assert array

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I have a question,

I am using phpunit WebTestCase in symfony 3.4

but I don't know how to assert it

and I get

> --- Expected
>
> +++ Actual
>
> @@ @@
>
> Array (
>
> -0 => 'amount' => 50
>
> +0 => Array (...)
>
> )

this is my ControllerTest

```
public function testmoneyIn()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $client->request('POST', '/bank/moneyin', array('amount' => 50));
    $query = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('b')
        ->from('BankBundle:entry', 'b')
        ->orderBy('b.created_at', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults(1);
    $data = $query->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
    $this->assertEquals(['amount' => 50],$data);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are testing a result set, I would expect it to be an array of rows from the database, in

```
$this->assertEquals(['amount' => 50],$data);
```

you only have the data for 1 row of data, which is what you want, but I would expect it to be

```
$this->assertEquals([['amount' => 50]],$data);
```

Which means a row of data in a result set.

Comment: that is right, but when I try  `$this->assertEquals([['amount' => 50]],$data['amount']);` I get **Error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit\Util\ErrorHandler::handleError()** what should I fix it. Thank a lot.

Comment: As `$data` is a multidimensional array, you would need to reference the element you want, so in this case `$this->assertEquals(50,$data[0]['amount'])`